# How to include routes file outside of conf folder?

Tags: playframework, routes, sbt, playframework-2.3

In Play 2.3.8, is it possible to put routes files outside of the "conf" folder?

I have tried to add the other folder with the other routes files to both `unmanagedSourceDirectories` and `unmanagedResourceDriectories`, but they don't seem to get pick up from the routesCompiler task.

Thanks

Comment: you can not call it, you can divide you route file but can not place it in other folder that conf, even the divided conf files should be in conf folder.

Comment: @RakeshChouhan Do I have to follow any naming convention for the divided route files? Say I have conf/routes and conf/scaffolded-routes which both contain routes, will both route files be compiled automatically? What is the ordering of the route priorities in that case? Let's assume Play 2.3.8 as the OP is using

Comment: @eljaydub You might have to name it `scaffolded.routes`, then add an entry in `routes` like `->     /     scaffolded.Routes` (notice the capitalized Routes)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might be able to do it in Play 2.4.

Back then, it was hard-coded to look into `confDirectory`.

But [this change](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/commit/7095307027f53c30c28d911efe40aada056103c6#diff-73d7ffa37e0ecc70d95d552bf5bc9f12L139) has made it to look into `unmanagedResourceDirectories`.